# Manage null values in LISTAGG

Tags: database, db2, listagg

I have a table of Policies and a table of Customers. For each policy I can have many customers. What I want to do is wrap the customers data in one record grouped by PolicyId.

So this is my query:

```
SELECT p.Id AS POLICY, LISTAGG(c.Name || ',' || c.Address || ',' || c.Phone || '||') AS CUSTOMERS
FROM Policies p
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.PolicyId = p.Id
WHERE p.Id = 'AXSD1234'
GROUP BY p.Id
```

The problem I have is that if one of the customer fields is null, the whole value retrieved in CUSTOMERS string becomes null as well. So if I have a Customers table like the following:

```
+----+----------+------+------------+-------+
| Id | PolicyId | Name |  Address   | Phone |
+----+----------+------+------------+-------+
|  1 | AXSD1234 | Jhon | Street 123 |  1234 |
|  2 | AXSD1234 | Anna | NULL       |  2345 |
+----+----------+------+------------+-------+
```

I would expect to retrieve something like this:

```
+----------+------------------------------------+
|  POLICY  |            CUSTOMERS               |
+----------+------------------------------------+
| AXSD1234 | John,Street 123,1234||Anna,,2345|| |
+----------+------------------------------------+
```

But instead I get this:

```
+----------+-----------+
|  POLICY  | CUSTOMERS |
+----------+-----------+
| AXSD1234 | NULL      |
+----------+-----------+
```

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening other than using NVL or the like on each field of the LISTAGG?

Maybe there is a completely different approach to this?

Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: Coalesce (or NVL) is the way to work round that. So what dies restrict you from using it that way?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a way of doing it without having to check every field individually because the actual query has tons of fields in differents LISTAGG, and various types all around. But yeah I presumed that it was the only option. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COALESCE is the only way.

```
SELECT p.Id AS POLICY, LISTAGG(COALESCE(c.Name,'') || ',' || COALESCE(c.Address) || ',' || COALESCE(c.Phone) || '||') AS CUSTOMERS
FROM Policies p
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.PolicyId = p.Id
WHERE p.Id = 'AXSD1234'
GROUP BY p.Id
```

If you have a lot of columns, I guess you could generate your statements from the system catalog to save some typing

Comment: Correct asnwer it is then. Thank you.